# JQuery Mobile Listviews w/collapsibles inside panel – random extra vertical pixels in Chrome v67

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jquery-mobile, removing-whitespace

I'm seeing some odd behavior that recently surfaced for me after the recent Chrome v67 update (tested in both Mac El Cap and on Windows 10 so far).

Using JQuery Mobile, I have some collapsibles nested inside a panel widget acting as a menu. This was working flawlessly for some time, but when I got temporarily sidetracked and then returned to the project, I noticed that now, in Chrome (v67 of which was released in late May, while I was away from the project), I was getting random 1px vertical spaces (white horizontal lines) between some menu items when opening the menu and then expanding a collapsible. It's impossible to predict which items will be effected, and even inspecting them is difficult, as the extra space disappears/resolves on rollover or when opening the inspector.

So far, I'm not seeing this behavior in Safari or FF (Mac), nor in Chrome v66 (Windows). While I'm unable to do more extensive cross browser testing at the moment, from what I'm seeing I'm operating under the assumption that something in the latest Chrome update is causing this issue.

I've sometimes seen similar unpredictable spacing issues when the browser's view is zoomed in/out slightly, but I've confirmed I'm viewing this at actual size.

It doesn't appear to be a CSS issue, as I'm not seeing a change in the computed values of an element after the space issue resolves on rollover. It appears for all the world to be some kind of Chrome rendering problem.

I realize this is a rather specific set of circumstances, but has anyone else experienced anything similar in Chrome v67, and if so have you found a way to resolve it?

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates this odd behavior (it's easiest to see when opening "List 2 of 6"):

https://jsfiddle.net/halfacre/p349ghvf/5/

EDIT: The issue seems to be originating from the math in my JS. This script is meant to smooth-scroll the chosen submenu to the top of the viewport (as these are long lists, and without the visual cue it's easy to get lost), and was working beautifully until the latest Chrome update. I'm including said JS below. As I'm not a programmer or particularly stellar at math, this script is crossing my eyes a bit... could this be due to remainders or rounding issues?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("collapsibleexpand", ".ui-collapsible", function(e) {
    var self = $(this), 
        menu = $("#mainmenu"),
        pageY = $(document).scrollTop(),
        content = $(this).children(".ui-collapsible-content");
    content.hide();
    content.slideDown({
        duration: 300,
        step: function(now, fx) {
          if (fx.prop == "height") {
            var pct = ((100 * now) / fx.end),
              itemTop = $(self).offset().top,
              menuScrollTop = $(menu).scrollTop(),
              amt = (itemTop - pageY) / 100 * pct;
            menu.scrollTop(menuScrollTop + amt);
          }
        }
      }
    );
    e.stopPropagation(); // don't bubble up
  });

  $(document).on("collapsiblecollapse", ".ui-collapsible", function(e) {
    var content = $(this).children('.ui-collapsible-content');
    content.slideUp(300);
    e.stopPropagation(); // don't bubble up
  });
});
```

Thanks for taking a look.

EDIT 2: Screenshot of what I'm seeing:
[image]

Comment: Could You please post a screenshot, to be sure of what You mean? Did You investigated  `font-family: "Avenir LT W02 65 Medium"` and `line-height: 1.3` in your CSS? I see also Your custom style declarations before the JQM theme, Please try to put it after all the JQM styles (theme + structure)..

Comment: Thanks for the tips, deblocker. Those custom style declarations are just the custom themeroller theme, which according to themeroller is to go first. I did try moving it but it had no effect on this issue. I also tried the default JQM theme via a cdn with the same result.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I posted a screenshot of the weirdness above.

Comment: It is a problem of the padding in Your stylesheet. I strongly believe that You need to assign the padding to the JQM classes, instead of directly to `ul`, `li` and `h3`.

Comment: Okay, I tried applying the 0 padding to .ui-collapsible and .ui-collapsible-heading (presuming those were the JQM classes you meant – these were the classes given to li and h3 respectively) but the behavior persists.

Comment: If I remove the JS that applies the animation and repositioning, the issue resolves, which led me to believe that something in the calculations was the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong here, I believe the question is how to zero-pad the JQM `collapsible`, i.e. the `listview`and the `collapsible heading` inside the menu panel.

First, keep in mind that JQM is dynamically enhancing each `div` which has an attribute `data-role` by adding some DOM content and the corresponding CSS classes.

You can look at the JQM source code by searching for `mobile.collapsible` and You will find what's happen at widget instancing in the `_enhance()` function and what's happen when You click the collapsible heading in the `_handleExpandCollapse()` function.

Now, I strongly believe there is somewhere a conflict among the JQM classes and Your CSS styles:

```
li, ul {padding:0!important; }
h3{ margin:0!important;}
```

But, sadly, I am not able to explain to You why this happens, as You said, just only with the latest Chrome version. I also noticed these thin random lines, which belongs to the `panel-content` background.

Here is my proposal to reset the space between the panel inner and the content:

```
.ui-panel-inner { padding: 0 !important; }
.ui-panel-inner .ui-collapsible-content { padding: 0 !important; }
.ui-panel-inner .ui-listview { margin: 0 !important; }
.ui-panel-inner .ui-listview > .ui-li-static { padding: 0 !important; }
.ui-panel-inner .ui-listview > li h3 { margin: 0 !important; }
```

Instead of defining new rules, I am overriding the JQM styles. Now, I can't see any thin random line anymore.

Here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/98b4r3w5/ any feedback welcome.

---

Moreover: *a note aside*, if You need a centered page content and a smaller footer, I would do it the same way:

```
.ui-content { text-align:center; }
.ui-footer .ui-title { padding: 0 !important; }
```

Comment: Well, yesterday I would have sworn up and down that this couldn't be a padding issue, but I can't argue with results. Indeed, your Fiddle puts this to bed. More specificity did the trick. Wish like heck we knew why this is only an issue with the newest Chrome release, but I'm grateful for the clear info you've provided and for the edification.

Comment: @Halfacre: Your feedback is welcome. Sorry for the boring explanation inside my answer, but I was almost sure that there couldn't be (in this case) a rounding issue, because inside the `slideDown` function we reposition just only the container, not each single list items.

Comment: – far from boring, and no apologies necessary – in fact I'm still working on fully understanding/reconciling this strangeness, which I haven't encountered before. In retrospect I'd definitely have to agree that the individual `<li>`s shouldn't be affected by that function – grasping at straws, I suppose. Thanks again!